# Object as input variable in mutation: GraphQL - Apollo - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a React client-side project and a Node.js/GraphQL api in two separate repo's.

In my React app, I want to pass an object as variable type into my mutation. Here's how my mutation looks like:

```
export const CREATE_SPEAKER = gql`

  input Expertise {
    title: String!
    domain: String!
  }

  mutation CreateSpeaker(
    $name: String!
    $age: String!
    $nationality: String!
    $avatar: String!
    $expertise: Expertise!
  ) {
    createSpeaker(
      speakerInput: {
        name: $name
        age: $age
        nationality: $nationality
        avatar: $avatar
        expertise: $expertise
      }
    ) {
      name
      age
      nationality
      avatar
      expertise {
        title
        domain
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

In my Node.js project I have the following schema:

```
input SpeakerInput {
      name: String!
      age: String!
      expertise: ExpertiseInput!
      nationality: String!
      avatar: String
}

input ExpertiseInput {
      title: String!
      domain: String!
}
```

And my resolver:

```
createSpeaker: async args => {
    const { name, age, nationality, avatar, expertise } = args.speakerInput;

    const newSpeaker = new Speaker({
      name,
      age,
      nationality,
      avatar,
      expertise: {
        title: expertise.title,
        domain: expertise.domain
      }
    });

    try {
      return await newSpeaker.save();
    } catch (error) {
      throw ("Failed to create speaker:: ", error);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error when trying to create the speaker:

> Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Schema type definitions not
>   allowed in queries. Found: "InputObjectTypeDefinition"

Any suggestions/ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can't define additional types when sending requests to a GraphQL service and you don't need to -- just use the types you've already defined on the server (in this case `ExpertiseInput`:

```
$expertise: ExpertiseInput!
```

However, there's no need to use this many variables in the first place:

```
mutation CreateSpeaker($input: SpeakerInput!) {
  createSpeaker(speakerInput: $input) {
    name
    age
    nationality
    avatar
    expertise {
      title
      domain
    }
  }
}
```